# Issue while pushing new code in Github

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am trying to push code into Github using command,

```
git push -u origin master
```

But it is asking for username and password and when I enter username and password it is giving error as "remote: Invalid username or password."
[image]

My username is "saekhan". I tried this with saekhan, "saekhan", @saekhan and "@saekhan". Please tell me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you're in your Git directory, what is the output of `git remote get-url origin`?

Comment: My output is "https://github.com/saekhan/node-course-2-web-server.git"

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your password includes a special character.
Then you should need to percent encode it (see "[Percent-encoding reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters)")

Check also your `git config credential.helper`: with a recent Git, it should ask your credentials through a popup window to cache them in the Windows Credential Manager

```
git config credential.helper
```

Make sure you are using the latest [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

I see a https://github.com/saekhan/node-course-2-web-server, so make sure your remote url is set to that repo:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/saekhan/node-course-2-web-server
# or
git remote set-url https://github.com/saekhan/node-course-2-web-server
```

Comment: Yes, first I run git remote add command then I am trying to run 'git push -u origin master'

Comment: @S.R.KHAN Does it ask you for your credentials?

Comment: Sometimes and sometimes it gives error directly without asking password.

Comment: @S.R.KHAN you need to enter your GitHub account and password

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, you have read/write permissions to repository.

Check remote server:

```
git remote -v
```

At Git source code folder (at same level at where you seen hidden folder named `.git`)

```
git config user.name "YourFullName"
git config user.email "your_email_address@example.com"
```

then retry.

Comment: user.name user.email have nothing to do with GitHub authentication.

Comment: I tried but still got the same result.

Comment: @S.R.KHAN yes, because they have nothing to do with your issue.